# Are "Kosher Salts" Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, names, salt

Is "Kosher salt" supposed to be understood as certain salts that adhere to the Jewish religions dietary restrictions? I'm curious if this is so what about salt can make it kosher or non kosher?

Comment: FYI, a number of my Gentile co-workers told me that they need a few days to "brine" the Thanksgiving turkey. I didn't know what "brining" means. After they explained it to me, I suggested that they buy a kosher turkey. It's already been "brined".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Salt in and of itself is inherently Kosher. In most consumer and industrial applications, no kosher-sensitive ingredients are added to salt, so it can in fact be used without Kosher certification.

"Kosher salt" would actually be more properly named "[Kosher*ing* salt](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/614954/jewish/What-Is-Kosher-Salt.htm)." What is special about it is that it is coarse grained. This makes it suitable for preparing meat to be able to be cooked in a Kosher manner. In order for kosher meat to be cooked, it as to first be soaked, salted with coarse grained salt and rinsed in order to remove the blood. Standard table salt is too fine to be suitable.

Apparently some like the coarse grained property of the salt and use it instead of table salt.

Comment: Just like 'table salt' doesn't have to be used at a table, 'kosher salt' can be used for whatever purpose you want.

Comment: Hope this is covered by this Q: Can you clarify whether or not anti-caking agents are allowed or not. Was sure they are not, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosher_salt says (unsourced) these would be allowed? (Generally, I thought koshering salt means not to allow *any* additives)

Comment: @LangLangC, not sure it is part of the question, but Kosher certified Kosher salt would only use anti-caking agents that are themselves Kosher, however, they would be allowed if they are Kosher and might very well be used. You would have to ask the Kosher certifier or the company if they use them. As far as I know, they are not required to be on the ingredient panel.

Answer (score 2):

Salt itself is neither Kosher nor non-Kosher, but it is used to make meat Kosher by drawing off blood (after which, it is rinsed away). It's just like regular salt except it is much coarser and non-iodized.

Comment: Actually, pure salt itself is Kosher. That's just not why they call certain kinds of salt "Kosher Salt".